# BeautifulSoup Add new tag inside a child DIV of a parent DIV

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am a complete beginner with BeautifulSoup and I am now trying to insert a new tag into a children div of a parent  div.

Basically I have this HTML snippet:

```
 <div class=page-content>
  <div class="content-block">
   //Insert here!
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here is my current code:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open("index.html"), "lxml")

    div_page_content = soup.find("div", { "class" : "page-content" })
    content_block = div_page_content.findChildren()

    button_active = soup.new_tag('a')
    button_active.attrs['class'] = 'button active'
    button_active.append('This is a new button!')

    content_block.append(button_active)
    print content_block
```

I can fetch the page-content and his children content-block DIV, but the append function doesn't do anything, this is the output that I get:

```
 [<div class="content-block">\n</div>, <a class="button active">This is a new button!</a>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, I have to use findNext instead of findChildren. now the append is working fine.

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure the error wasn't the fact that you left out the quotation marks around your class? You've written `<div class=page-content>`
   instead of `<div class="page-content">`.

Comment: That is [perfectly valid HTML](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values), and is not the cause of OP's ***python*** problem.

Comment: I was alluding to BeautifulSoup, their encoders used to struggle with quotation marks, not HTML itself.